# Typora: prevent auto line break of table cell

Tags: css, markdown

Suppose a table with 8 more columns and various rows.

[image]

The excerpts are line feed (line break) automatically. I intend, it extends until an `<br>` is explicitly typed in.

How could I get it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSS style:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

Go to **`File > Preference`** or press **`Ctrl+Comma`**. In Themes, click **`Open Theme Folder`**.

[image]

Open the CSS file of your theme. For example, I'm using *Github* theme.

[image]

I don't know if you want to prevent line break in a particular column or the complete table. So I'm providing several conditions. Use whatever you prefer. But I think, you want to use any one of first two conditions.

If you want to prevent line-break in all data cells of the table (except header cells), add following code in CSS file:

```
td {white-space: nowrap;}
```

If you want to prevent line-break for all data cells (except header cells) in a particular column.

```
td:nth-child(2)  {white-space: nowrap;} /* I did it in 2nd column */
```

If you want to prevent line-break in all the header and data cells of the table:

```
tr {white-space: nowrap;}
```

If you want to prevent line-break in all the header and data cells in a particular column:

```
th:nth-child(3), /* e.g., in 3rd column */
td:nth-child(3) {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I found it not the problem of {white-space: nowrap;}, but the default least width of each cell, I read the file with no minimal length defined in table cell.

Comment: search word "width" through the file, found `max-width: 860px; `, there's no width defined for table data cell.

Comment: @avirate Do you want to define custom width to table cells?

Comment: @avirate You can't define width for table cells. They are equally divided according to the max-width. This is built-in behavior of Typora.

Comment: I want to reduce their default minimal width,

Comment: It's not possible to define specific width for cells. You can only define it for complete table. You may reduce length of complete table but not of the cells. Cells are always automatically organized with equal width. This width then changes according to the input. Sadly, Typora restricts us to customize tables.

Comment: Is it padding which determine the minimal width of each cell? sorry for the disturbing, I should learn CSS.

Comment: Padding creates **extra space within an element**. But it is totally different from width. It's like margin. In CSS, margin creates extra space around an element while padding within an element. More padding you increase, it will of course increase the width of the cell (due to extra space within the cell), but it will not increase the width of input area of the cell. See the instant effect of [padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding). Play with values in demo there. You'll understand.